# Is $\text{Bow}(X,T)$ a Banach Space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ergodic-theory, thermodynamic-formalism

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence space and $T:X\to X$ the left  shift mapping. Define the vector space $\text{Bow}(X,T)$ as 
$$
\text{Bow}(X,T)=\{f\in C^{0}(X);~\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{d_n(x,y)\leq 1/2} |S_nf(x)-S_nf(y)|<\infty\},
$$
where

- $S_nf=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^j$;
- $d_n(x,y)=\max\{d(T^jx,T^jy),~j=0,\ldots,n-1    \}   $;
- $d(x,y)=2^{-N}$, where $N=\inf\{i\in \mathbb{N}\;; x_i\neq y_i\}$.

Consider in the $\text{Bow}(X,T)$ space the norm 
$$
|f|_{\text{Bow}}
=
2\,\|f\|_{\infty}
+\sup_{n\geq 1}\ 
\max_{d_n(x,y)\leq 1/2}|\,S_nf(x)-S_nf(y)\,|.
$$

> **Question:** Is $(\text{Bow}(X,T),|\cdot|_{\text{Bow}} )$ a Banach Space?

Comment: What do you mean by $C^0(X)$?

Comment: @BenWillson in this context $C^0(X)$ is usually the space of all continuous functions taking values on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It would be sufficient to show to show that the unit ball of your space is closed in $C^0(X)$. Did you try this?